# Concatenate columns pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've created a dataframe which varies according to the data which will be used as input, so this df can be anywhere between 3 and 100 columns long. I am looking for a way to only have 3 columns where all following columns (regardless of the amount as this is unknown) are concatenated in the third column (a sort of list with ',')

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
df = (
    pd.concat(
        [df[df.columns[:2]],
         df[df.columns[2:]].apply(list, axis=1)],
        axis=1)
)
```

To filter out NAN you can use a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

result = (
    pd.concat(
        [df[df.columns[:2]],
         df[df.columns[2:]].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in ['nan', 'NaN', 'None', np.NAN]], axis=1)],
        axis=1)
)
```

If you want comma-separated value instead of list use:

```
import numpy as np

result = pd.concat(
    [
        df[df.columns[:2]],
        df[df.columns[2:]].apply(
            lambda x: ', '.join(
                i for i in x if i not in ['nan', 'NaN', 'None', np.NAN]
            ),
            axis=1,
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed concatenate them but the issue there is that I now have to filter all None values out of these lists within a df

Comment: updated my answer just add the value in the list (in lambda function) that you wanna exclude @Fisqkuz

Comment: Again, valuable answer - Thanks!. Do you have any tips on how to do the same but without making it a list? Because trying to work with this data with lists as cell value is living hell.